# C declaration for extern function not issuing a warning on #args mismatch

Tags: c

please consider the following two C files. As you can see func is defined in file2.c but called from file1.c.

```
file1.c
------------------------------
extern int func(int a, int b);

:::::
int some_func() 
{
 ....
 func(1,2);
}
------------------------------



file2.c
-------------------------------
int func(int a, int b, char *c, int d)
{
 function body;
}
------------------------------
```

Questions:

1. Why does this code compiles well, there is no warning/ error in terms of
     arguments mismatch as the func actually takes 4 args but only 2 provided.
2. When I modify the declaration of 'func' in file1.c to

   extern int func(int a, int b, char *c, int d);

then I get appropriate error message from the compiler but not the linker. I
suppose as its declared as extern linker should give me the error. 
Please correct me where I am wrong.

I am on 64 bit ubuntu 12.04, gcc version 4.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

A C compilation produces an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) on Linux etc...), e.g. `file1.o` etc. In that object file, the signature of function is *not* kept (only their name). FWIW, C++ but not C use [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to encode in the name the signature of the function.

The correct way would be to declare the correct signature of `func`  in some common `myheader.h` and to `#include` that header both in `file1.c` and `file2.c` (then a definition of `func` with an incompatible signature would give a diagnostic message).

BTW, if you compiled *and linked* with `gcc -flto -Wall -g` (at least with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) like the latest GCC 4.9), i.e. with *link-time optimization*, almost *all warnings*, and *debug info*, you might have got some warning.

Your GCC 4.6 is quite old, you should consider upgrading it.

Comment: Also, `extern` is redundant in that case.

Comment: Thanks Basile Starynkevitch for the answer that explains